# stringWithContentsOfURL gives null value

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Hi I'm trying to get a number from a text file in my server but i'm getting a null value this is the code... I have reed many similar posts trying to solve the problem but non of them has been useful

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.trailrunningcamp.cl/version.txt"];
NSError* error = nil;
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];

NSLog(@"Content = %@", content );
```

I have added this code to my plist but still got the same result

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
   <dict>
     <key>trailrunningcamp.cl</key>
      <dict>
        <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
         <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
         <true/>
         <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
        <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
     <true/>
      <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
     <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
     <string>TLSv1.1</string>
     </dict>
   </dict>
 </dict>
```

I'm using Xcode 7.2.1 and OS X El Capitan 10.11.3.... before that code worked fine (a year ago) but with the new Xcode does not work... Is it a missconfiguration or a code error?

Comment: maybe its because of App Transport Security. See in your console if there is any error regarding it.

Comment: xcode can only make https connections unless you add some permissions to allow http connections in your app plist.

Comment: I already add the exception and does not work

Comment: Did you check console messages when the error happens to see if there are clues there?

Comment: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The file “version.txt” couldn’t be opened." UserInfo={NSURL=http://www.trailrunningcamp.cl/version.txt}